# Quick Look QLPreviewPanel invisible in LSUIElement agent app on 10.6

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, quicklook

Is there a way to show the QLPreviewPanel in an agent app (LSUIElement == YES) on Mac OS X 10.6? It works on 10.7. The frame of the panel is correct and everything, it’s just not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in an old thread on CocoaDev, where the issue was showing alert panels in agent apps in general:

[Alert dialog in agent app](http://osdir.com/ml/cocoa-dev/2009-08/msg01370.html)

Solution: One must call [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES] in order to make the panel appear.